# Invoking Lambda with API responses 'socket closed' error sometimes

Tags: aws-lambda

Since the EC2 instance calling Lambda was moved to a private VPC, Lambda calls sometimes respond with a 'socket closed' error. (25% chance of failure)

I never had this error before moving to a private VPC.

Lambda monitoring shows all requests as successful.

I am suspecting that the nat gateway that we are going through to call lambda inside the private vpc is not keeping the connection alive.

Has anyone else experienced something like this?

Thanks